# JavaScript function return undefined in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a javascript function name with binaryToOther and another function chunks

```
 function chunks(array, size) {
    var results = [];
    array = array.reverse();
    while (array.length) {
        results.push(array.splice(0, size));
    }
    results = results.reverse()
    return results.map(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
        return currentValue.reverse();
    });
};

function binaryToOther(binaryNumber, baseNumber) {
    var binaryArr = binaryNumber.toString().split("");
    switch (baseNumber) {
        case 10:
            var keys = binaryArr.map(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
                return index;
            }).reverse();
            return {
                "number": binaryArr,
                "position": keys
            };

    }
}
```

I am calling the binaryToOther function by stateParams but it return undefined.

```
    console.log($stateParams.number);
    console.log($stateParams.to);

    console.log(binaryToOther($stateParams.number, $stateParams.to));
    console.log(binaryToOther(101010,10));
```

**Output**

```
101010
10
undefined
Object {number: Array[6], position: Array[6]}
```

Comment: Could $stateParams.to be a string instead of an int?

Comment: Thanks @Eric N. It's working after parseInt.